# How can I erase all items from a vector? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, memset

I am just trying to make all my elements `0` without doing it manually with

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    v[i] = 0;
```

I found online that i can use this command: `v.clear();` but it doesn't work:

> error: request for member 'clear' in 'v', which is of non-class type 'int [101]'

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int n,i,v[101];

int main() {
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>v[i];

    v.clear();
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because’v’ is an array not a vector.

Comment: *"I found online that i can use this command: `v.clear();`"* -if some online site states you can do that with a native array, i.e. `int v[101];` then I  suggest you avoid returning to that site; it's rubbish.

Comment: You don't have a vector there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill), that can be used with C-style arrays, too:

```
std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array. Arrays in C++ do not have methods. What you need is to call the standard C function memset.

For example

```
#include <cstring>

//...

std::memset( v, 0, n * sizeof( int ) );
```

Also indices for arrays in C++ start from 0. So use for loops like

```
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe, you can use `std::array` , it can also specify the size like `int v[101]` .
   Then, you can use `v = {0}` to make make all my elements `0`.
   For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    array<int, 101> v;
    for (auto &elem : v)
        cin >> elem;
    v = {0};
    for (auto elem : v)
        cout << elem << " ";
}
```

2. If you don't like `std::array`, you can also do like the following.

```cpp
int v[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *p = v;
while (*p++ = 0, *p != 0) { };
```

3. In fact, I think that `std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);` that user **Evg** answered is best.